# Combining date and time columns into one column introduces NA values

Tags: r

I have a data frame consisting of hourly data for the past 30 years. When I combine the `DATE` column with the `TIME` column to create a new column of `DateTime`, I get periodic `NA` values every 8000-9000 rows. Any idea why this is happening and how to not make it happen?

Example Data

```
# Create dataframe
start <- as.Date("1993-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2022-06-02")
hours <- as.data.frame(rep(seq(0,2300,100), 10745))
colnames(hours)[1] <- "TIME"
dates <- as.data.frame(rep(seq(start,end,by = "day"), 24))
colnames(dates)[1] <- "DATE"
dates <- dates %>% arrange(DATE)
x <- cbind(dates,hours)

# Convert the time from number to character (HH:MM)
x$TIME <- substr(as.POSIXct(sprintf("%04.0f", x$TIME), format='%H%M'), 12, 16)

# Combine date and time into one column
x$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(as.character(paste(x$DATE, x$TIME)), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

# See rows with NA values for DateTime
which(is.na(x$DateTime))
```

Comment: I tried with `ymd_hm` and it is giving 0 NAs i.e. `sum(is.na(ymd_hm(paste(x$DATE, x$TIME))))
[1] 0`

Comment: Yes, there are zero NA values in ```DATE``` and ```TIME``` but when you combine them into one column many NA values are introduced, that is the problem.

Comment: what I meant is that when you convert to POSIXct with `ymd_hm`, i didn't find any NA

Comment: That fixed it! For anyone else who comes across this error, the code is: ```x$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(ymd_hm(paste(x$DATE, x$TIME)), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")```. You will need to load the ```lubridate``` package to use the ```ymd_hm``` function.

Comment: You don't need `as.POSIXct` wrapping as ymd_hm returns POSIXct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `ymd_hm` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
x$DateTime <-ymd_hm(paste(x$DATE, x$TIME))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like:

```
from = strptime("1993-01-01 00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
to = strptime("2022-06-22 23:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
x = seq.POSIXt(from, to, by="hour")
```